# SQL Order by Start time and endtime

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a table SHIFTBREAKTIME (ID, starttime time(7), endtime time(7))

Sample Values

```
ID      StartTime   endTime
1       13:00       13:45
2       9:00        9:45
3       11:00       11:50
```

I want to display the above data in the following order (low to high)

```
ID      StartTime   endTime
1       9:00        9:45
2       11:00       11:50
3       13:00       13:45
```

I'm unable to Sort in that order. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `order by StartTime asc, endTime asc`?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by unable to sort. Is it coming up with any error? do you have the SQL query? In the meantime, you could try order by startTime, endTime

Comment: The only reason both would be needed is if you have multiple records with the same start time and want to see them in the order of shortest duration..

Comment: Why are the `id` values changing?  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the data in your table with a select statement. If ID 1 has a start time of 13:00 then it will always be this way, unless you update the info first.

Sorting means which entire row should be on top of the list and which entire row should be second.... but the data in each row stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the `id` values based on the sorted order, you can do so using variables in MySQL:

```
set @id := 0;

update t
    set id= (@id := @id + 1)
    order by starttime;
```

If you just want to select the values with a sequential id:

```
select (@id := @id + 1), starttime, endtime
from t cross join
     (select @id := 0) params
order by starttime;
```

Comment: What makes you think it's MySql?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . Although supported by other databases, I happen to associate `time(7)` with MySQL.